# Browser going in a loop while using the 301 redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am using WordPress and I have to redirect the some URLs like

```
https://test.com/demo to https://test.com/demo/a/b/c/
https://test.com/example to https://test.com/example/a/b
https://test.com/xyz to https://test.com/xyz/a/b/c/d/

https://test.com/xyz/a/ to https://test.com/pqr/
```

I tried the below 301 code but it's not working, My browser is going in a loop, and the URL showing multiple times.

```
Redirect 301 http://test.com/demo http://test.com/demo/a/b/c/
Redirect 301 http://test.com/example http://test.com/example/a/b
Redirect 301 https://test.com/xyz https://test.com/xyz/a/b/c/d/
Redirect 301 https://test.com/xyz/a/ https://test.com/pqr/
```

**.htaccess code**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


RewriteRule ^demo$ /demo/a/b/c/ [R=301,L
RewriteRule ^example$ /example/a/b/c/ [R=301,L]


</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

The directives you've posted won't do anything since the `Redirect` directive takes a root-relative URL-path as the *source* URL, not an absolute URL (with scheme + hostname). You may be seeing the result of a cached redirect (301 - permanent - redirects are cached persistently by the browser. Test first with 302s to avoid caching issues.)

However, the `Redirect` directive is not the correct tool for the job, for a couple of reasons:

- The mod_alias `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching, so matches anything that *starts* with the stated URL-path. (So, in your example, the first three redirects would indeed result in a redirect-loop and the 4th would never be processed.)
- You should avoid mixing mod_rewrite (part of the WordPress code block) and mod_alias in the same context since you can get unexpected conflicts. mod_rewrite always executes first, despite the apparent order of the directives.

Try the following instead, using mod_rewrite, at the top of your `.htaccess` file. *Before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` code block.

```
RewriteRule ^demo$ /demo/a/b/c/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^example$ /example/a/b/c/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^xyz$ /xyz/a/b/c/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^xyz/a/$ /pqr/ [R=301,L]
```

NB: There is no slash prefix on the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Comment: I tested the first line code of code but it's not redirecting. Checking others

Comment: Make sure all caches are cleared. If it's still not working then please update your question with your complete `.htaccess` file with these directives in place.

Comment: I clear the cache and checked in a private browser  but same issue. Updated code in the question

Comment: @user9437856 You've put the directives in the wrong place. As I stated in my answer, these directives must go "at the top of your `.htaccess` file, before the `# BEGIN WordPress` code block". There is also a _warning_ in the code comments that you should not manually edit the code between the WordPress comment markers.

Comment: Let me check again

Comment: I added the code at the top, cleared the cache but still not redirecting

Comment: @user9437856 The code you added in the question has a closing square bracket missing on the first directive - is that just a typo in the question? Otherwise, that should have resulted in a 500 error?

Comment: That is the typo, I am not getting 500 types error

Comment: @user9437856 Please update your question with the revised `.htaccess` file with these directives in-place. What is the actual URL you are requesting? Check the network traffic in the browser dev tools - what is the HTTP request/response you are seeing?

Comment: Let me try that. Give me sometime

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240325/discussion-between-user9437856-and-mrwhite).

Comment: I tried the code but it's not redirecting. I have shared the code in the chat.

Comment: @user9437856 What is the actual URL you are requesting? Is `demo` a physical directory? Are you using WordPress "pretty" permalinks or does `index.php` appear in the URL. "Check the network traffic in the browser dev tools - what is the HTTP request/response you are seeing?" (NB: As mentioned above, you should be _testing_ this with 302 redirects.) - When you responded with "That is the typo" - do you mean it was just a typo in your question or was it a typo in your actual code?

Comment: the demo is the page that I created on the WordPress, I am using the post permalink link so there is no index.php. HTTP request is showing empty, Responsive showing the /demo page content

Comment: @user9437856 "HTTP request is showing empty" - It can't be "empty"? (That would imply there is no HTTP request.) Please include the complete HTTP _response_ headers (from the browser dev tools) in your question. Are you behind a front-end caching proxy, load balancer, CDN, ...?

Comment: Ok. i thought you are talking about the request. I am getting the Get request link like http://test.com/demo/

Comment: @user9437856 I mentioned both the request and the response. Knowing the HTTP response headers would be the next step to debug this. HOWEVER... "I am getting the Get request link like `test.com/demo/`" - your link has a trailing slash? There is no trailing slash in your example and this is omitted from the directive above. (?)

Comment: I apologize for my bad, Yes, there is a slash after the page name.

Comment: @user9437856 If the URL you are requesting includes a trailing slash then you will obviously need to include the trailing slash in the regex that matches the URL-path. eg. `RewriteRule ^demo/$ /demo/a/b/c/ [R=301,L]` or make it optional so that it matches both with and without a trailing slash. eg. `RewriteRule ^demo/?$ /demo/a/b/c/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Yes, I think this time it's working. Let me confirm you ASAP